# Is there any benefitis on using a Boundfield over Template Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

For ASP.NET GridView:

I want to know if there are  any benefits on using a `Boundfield` over Template Field.

The only benefit that I can think of ,is using `boundfield` simpler and it needs less code.

I'm  plannning to get rid of all bound fields in my code and replacing them with Template fields, mostly because I don't like using hardcoded column index to get values from bound field.

```
string name=GridViewCurrentRow.Cells[13].Text
```

I would rather use `FindControl("ControlID")` method of Row class and this seem to be only doable if I use a template field.

Am I missing something or are there any concerns ? Please share.

Comment: Use Template fields if you need a different rendering of that column field instead the default rendering (bound fields)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `FindControl("ControlID")` with both BoundField and TemplateField as its a GridViewRow's class not the both Fields.

While on other hand:

- BoundField is used when you only want to display text/data as default.
- TemplateField gives you more control on customization of your data row in GridView in different designs and styles. It allows you multiple options of HTML and Web Controls.

[BoundField and TemplateField](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23146659/BoundField-vs-TemplateField-Gridview.html).

Comment: A bound field which is read-only does not contain any controls.  Therefore you cannot use FindControl.

Comment: yes its only use for displaying data. the findcontrol will read data from the cells.